# Cant compile Boost C++ Network Library 0.5

Tags: visual-studio-2008, compiler-construction, boost

[Boost Network](http://cpp-netlib.github.com//html/index.html)

I am trying out this code in a small console app on windows (VS2008) but cant compile it. Have linked to the boost.system library.  Am i missing a header, #define or another library?

Headers

```
#include <boost/network/protocol/http/client.hpp>
#include <iostream>
```

Errors

```
using native typeof
1>c:\dev\3rdparty\boostproposed\cpp-netlib-0.5\boost\network\uri\http\detail\parse_specific.hpp(74) : error C2065: 'not' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\dev\3rdparty\boostproposed\cpp-netlib-0.5\boost\network\uri\http\detail\parse_specific.hpp(74) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'iequals'
1>c:\dev\3rdparty\boostproposed\cpp-netlib-0.5\boost\network\uri\http\detail\parse_specific.hpp(74) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with a missing include inside the library itself. There are plenty of other compilation issues with cpp-netlib 0.5 on Windows so I suggest you use the "bleeding edge" code, which can be found here:

http://github.com/mikhailberis/cpp-netlib/tree/0.6-devel

Comment: I have the same problem, and I get a huge list of compile errors no matter which version of netlib i use (0.5 or 0.6). Is there some special procedure for compiling it?
(the rest of the boost seems to be working fine)
Here is the command I use for compiling:
g++ some_example.cpp -I (path_to_boost) -I (path_to_netlib)

Comment: We're on 0.7 now, so things may be different again.  If you're still having troubles, please report your difficulties on the issue tracker (http://github.com/cpp-netlib/cpp-netlib/issues), including your platform, compiler, version and the error message (yes, I know it can get pretty hairy, but we're working on it).